# Android Lib Unit Tests - Compare local lib against last deployed version

Tags: android, gradle, junit

I've been asked to develop some unit tests for an Android lib some coworkers mantain. The thing is that, for some reason, they want a test that execute the same operation in the lib from the project and in the lib currently deployed (last stable version), ensuring the output of both are the same.

As you can imagine, I can't import the deployed lib, cause the classes package are the same that the current project and it does not compile. I've been looking for some kind of solution that adds a suffix or something like that to the imported or the local lib package while executing the tests, but I did't find anything.

Do you know some workaround to achieve this??